# Python - Can I access the object who call me?

Tags: python, oop, function-calls

If I have this:

```
class A:
    def callFunction(self, obj):
        obj.otherFunction()

class B:
    def callFunction(self, obj):
        obj.otherFunction()

class C:
    def otherFunction(self):
        # here I wan't to have acces to the instance of A or B who call me.

...

# in main or other object (not matter where)
a = A()
b = B()
c = C()
a.callFunction(c) # How 'c' know that is called by an instance of A...
b.callFunction(c) # ... or B
```

Despite the design or other issues, this is only a question of an inquiring mind.

***Note: This has to be done without changing*** `otherFunction` ***signature***

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this is for debugging purposes you can use inspect.currentframe():

```
import inspect

class C:
    def otherFunction(self):
        print inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals
```

Here is the output:

```
>>> A().callFunction(C())
{'self': <__main__.A instance at 0x96b4fec>, 'obj': <__main__.C instance at 0x951ef2c>}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick hack, get the stack and from last frame get locals to access self

```
class A:
    def callFunction(self, obj):
        obj.otherFunction()

class B:
    def callFunction(self, obj):
        obj.otherFunction()

import inspect

class C:
    def otherFunction(self):
        lastFrame = inspect.stack()[1][0]
        print lastFrame.f_locals['self'], "called me :)"

c = C()

A().callFunction(c)
B().callFunction(c)
```

output:

```
<__main__.A instance at 0x00C1CAA8> called me :)
<__main__.B instance at 0x00C1CAA8> called me :)
```

Answer (score 1):

Examine the stack with the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) with `inspect.stack()`. You can then get the instance from each element in the list with `f_locals['self']`

Comment: But i want to acces the OBJECT who is calling me.. not just the name of the class.. I wan't to acces the instance

Comment: Use the inspect module to access `tb_frame` in the each item of the stacktrace and then you can find the instance in `f_locals['self']`