# AS3 - Can I have access to the object (or function) who call me?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, callback

I've asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387756/python-can-i-access-the-object-who-call-me) same question with Python.

Now I like to know if this can be done in AS3.

If I have something like this:

```
package
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        private function A():void { C() }
        private function B():void { C() }

        private function C():void
        {
            // who is the caller, A or B ???
        }

        public function SomeClass()
        {
            A()
            B()
        }
    }
}
```

Despite the design or other issues, this is only a question of an inquiring mind.

***Note: I like to have an access to an instance of the caller function so I can call that caller function (if I want to)***

### Note 2 : This has to be done without changing `function C()` signature

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Unlike previous versions of ActionScript, ActionScript 3.0 has no arguments.caller  property. To get a reference to the function that called the current function, you must pass a reference to that function as an argument."

From http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/arguments.html

That's the only way you can do that, otherwise you'll need to make a global variable to tell what function is calling C

Comment: If you don't want to change C signature, only with a global var.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can be done. You can do something like

```
private function C():void
{
  var e:Error = new Error();
  var stack:String = e.getStackTrace();
  //analyze stack and find out which function called it.
}
```

this is ugly but it would work.

Comment: Yes, I know this, but read Note: "I like to have an instance of the caller function" and using the stack I only have the name of the function. Not the object or the function object

Comment: you might be able to get that once you have the name. look here:
http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=197943

Comment: Still the same, that way I can acces the method name, but what if that function is public and is called by other object? How can I call the function over the object who call me? To do that I need the function instance or the object (owner of the function) instance and the function name.