# How to find the name of a variable that was passed to a function?

Tags: python, variables, reflection

In C/C++, I have often found it useful while debugging to define a macro, say `ECHO(x)`, that prints out the variable name and its value (i.e. `ECHO(variable)` might print `variable 7`).  You can get the variable name in a macro using the 'stringification' operator `#` as described [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html).  Is there a way of doing this in Python?

In other words, I would like a function

```
def echo(x):
    #magic goes here
```

which, if called as `foo=7; echo(foo)` (or `foo=7; echo('foo')`, maybe), would print out `foo 7`.  I realise it is trivial to do this if I pass both the variable and its name to the function, but I use functions like this a lot while debugging, and the repetition always ends up irritating me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not really solution, but may be handy (anyway you have `echo('foo')` in question):

```
def echo(**kwargs):
    for name, value in kwargs.items():
        print name, value

foo = 7
echo(foo=foo)
```

**UPDATE:** Solution for `echo(foo)` with `inspect`

```
import inspect
import re

def echo(arg):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    try:
        context = inspect.getframeinfo(frame.f_back).code_context
        caller_lines = ''.join([line.strip() for line in context])
        m = re.search(r'echo\s*\((.+?)\)$', caller_lines)
        if m:
            caller_lines = m.group(1)
        print caller_lines, arg
    finally:
        del frame

foo = 7
bar = 3
baz = 11
echo(foo)
echo(foo + bar)
echo((foo + bar)*baz/(bar+foo))
```

Output:

```
foo 7
foo + bar 10
(foo + bar)*baz/(bar+foo) 11
```

It has the smallest call, but it's sensitive to newlines, e.g.:

```
echo((foo + bar)*
      baz/(bar+foo))
```

Will print:

```
baz/(bar+foo)) 11
```

Comment: That second solution is extremely clever.  While working out how it works, I found a duplicate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503363/can-you-translate-this-debugging-macro-from-c-to-python) - though your regex is a bit more robust than the similar answer given there.

Comment: great answer, thanks.  could you briefly explain how the regex works?

Comment: @Ferguzz, It searches for `echo`, then `\s*` - 0 or many spaces, `\(` - parentheses, `(.+?)\)$` - non-greddy search for all symbols before `\)` (parentheses) at end of line (`$`). More info at http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html. You can also [debug regexps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/143636/1052325). Try in interactive Python session: `re.compile(r'echo\s*\((.+?)\)$', re.DEBUG)`

Answer (score 3):

```
def echo(x):
    import inspect
    print "{0}: {1}".format(x, inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals[x])
y = 123
echo('y')
# 'y: 123'
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2387854/16361

Note that this can cause GC issues:

http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack

It will also turn off people who have been burned by messing with frames, and may leave a bad taste in your mouth. But it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that has you type a bit more to call it. It relies on the [locals](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) built-in function:

```
def print_key(dictionary, key):
    print key, '=', dictionary[key]


foo = 7
print_key(locals(), 'foo')
```

---

An `echo` with the semantics you mentioned is also possible, using the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module. However, do read the warnings in inspect's documentation. This is an ugly non-portable hack (it doesn't work in all implementations of Python). Be sure to only use it for debugging.

The idea is to look into the [locals](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) of the calling function. The inspect module allows just that: calls are represented by frame objects linked together by the `f_back` attribute. Each frame's local and global variables are available (there are also builtins, but you're unlikely to need to print them).

You may want to explicitly delete any references frame objects to prevent reference cycles, as explained in [inspect docs](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack), but this is not strictly necessary – the garbage collection will free them sooner or later.

```
import inspect

def echo(varname):
    caller = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    try:
        value = caller.f_locals[varname]
    except KeyError:
        value = caller.f_globals[varname]
    print varname, '=', value
    del caller

foo = 7
echo('foo')
```