# Python logging variables: interpolation or format?

Tags: python, logging

What is the recommended method for logging variables using Python `logging`, and why is it better?

Old-style interpolation:

```
apple = "green"
logger.debug("apple is %s", apple)
```

or

New-style `.format()`

```
logger.debug("apple is {}".format(apple))
```

I have heard that [interpolation is preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619790/pylint-message-logging-format-interpolation), because it only evaluates the string if it's going to be printed, but I haven’t verified if it actually matters.

Comment: probably doesn't matter. In 99% of cases, if the run time of your logging is significant, something is wrong.

Comment: This is covered in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#optimization)

Comment: @gbtimmon I'm not sure I agree with that sentiment. I might dump `debug` logging all over my code during testing with any arbitrarily long string output. The fact that interpolation means I can simply remove all of that overhead by changing the logging level means I don't have to go back and hash a load of lines out.

Comment: New-style interpolation is neither of those.  Introduced at 3.6 you can use an "f" string:  `logger.debug(f"apple is {apple}")`

Comment: @ronganjosh Meh well if you want to do that much debug statements I suppose thats a personal choice, but my point was that it would have to be a TON of logging before its going to be the bottle neck in your process. If you program spends more time logging then anything else, then I think you are logging too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
logger.debug("apple is {}".format(apple))
```

```
logger.debug(f"apple is {apple}")
```

New-style formatting **will always build a string**. If this is expensive (e.g. logging a large pandas DataFrame), this will impact performance.

---

```
logger.debug("apple is %s", apple)
```

Old-style interpolation **only builds the logging string if the message will actually end up being logged**. If you app's loglevel is one of INFO/WARNING/ERROR/CRITICAL, it will only log messages of at least that loglevel. So this DEBUG-level message would not get logged *and the interpolation is skipped*.

In conclusion, yes, interpolation saves formatting effort (effectively calls to `__str__`) -- if this actually matters depends on your app.

Answer (score 2):

Use `=` feature of *f-strings* since Python **3.8**

`logger.debug(f"{apple=}")`

Output `apple=green`.
See [Python: Print a variable's name and value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000934/python-print-a-variables-name-and-value).