# Print/log the names and values of all parameters a function was called with (without eval)

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, parameters

When a function is called, I would like to print (or log) the names and values of the parameters it was called with. Something like:

```
>>> def foo(bar, baz):
>>>    do_something() 
>>> foo(5, 'test')
# would print: foo(bar=5, baz='test')
```

I can manually add print/logging calls to each function, but this is a pain as the functions I am concerned with grow/change over time and are part of an abstract interface that can be extended in other places.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/how-to-get-method-parameter-names) mentions how to get the parameter names, but doesn't mention how to get their values when called. I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000934/python-print-a-variables-name-and-value) which uses `eval` and works on a known set of parameters. I'd really like to avoid `eval` and be able to do it for an arbitrary set of parameters.

For context, this code is used for debugging a hardware interface. When the hardware isn't present it prints (or logs) the IO requests instead of sending them to the hardware.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get method parameter names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/how-to-get-method-parameter-names)

Comment: May I ask *why*? In any case, on possibility is to replace explicit parameters with `**kwargs` which will return a dict

Comment: @OlvinRoght That's fine for getting the names, but how would I then get the values? Use `eval`?

Comment: @MatthewSalvatoreViglione, there's link to [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module docs, you can find there function which fits your requirements better. Combination of [`inspect.currentframe()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe) and [`inspect.getargvalues()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargvalues) should work. There's also [`inspect.formatargvalues()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.formatargvalues) which could be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you've add explanation how you want to apply this, I think best way will be to use [decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator). It's more universal solution, because you can add it to any function in your code and it will print all debug info if debug mode is on.

**Code:**

```
from functools import wraps

DEBUG = True

def debug_log(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if DEBUG:
            print(">> Called", function.__name__, "\n",
                {**dict(zip(function.__code__.co_varnames, args)), **kwargs})
        result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        if DEBUG:
            print(">>", function.__name__, "return:\n", result)
        return result
    return wrapper

@debug_log
def first_example(a, b, c):
    return 100

@debug_log
def second_example(d, e, f):
    return 200

first_example(10, 11, 12)
first_example(c=12, a=10, b=11)
second_example(13, 14, 15)
second_example(e=14, d=13, f=15)
DEBUG = False
first_example(0, 0, 0)
second_example(1, 1, 1)
```

**Output:**

```
>> Called first_example 
 {'a': 10, 'b': 11, 'c': 12}
>> first_example return:
 100
>> Called first_example 
 {'c': 12, 'a': 10, 'b': 11}
>> first_example return:
 100
>> Called second_example 
 {'d': 13, 'e': 14, 'f': 15}
>> second_example return:
 200
>> Called second_example 
 {'e': 14, 'd': 13, 'f': 15}
>> second_example return:
 200
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the name of a parameter if it was called without a keyword? I'm thinking using `inspect` like you mentioned earlier may be a good way

Comment: @MatthewSalvatoreViglione, you can use hack from MrNobody33's answer.

Comment: @OlvinRoght This will not work if the callable has no `__name__` attribute. For example, if you try to apply logging to My question is almost a duplicate of the the question you linked to aclass objects having a `__call__` method.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `func.__code__.co_varnames` like this:

```
def foo(bar, baz):
    magic_parameter_printing() 

bar=0
baz=None  
for var in foo.__code__.co_varnames:
    print(var,'= ',eval(var))
```

Output:

```
bar=0
baz=None
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a somewhat flawed answer, but it is different than some of the other answers I have seen. Hopefully, someone can post an even better answer, because my solution to the problem has some serious issues.

```py
import functools
import inspect

def print_calling_args(f):
    assert(callable(f))
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        siggy = inspect.signature(f)
        bound_siggy = siggy.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        all_sargs = ", ".join(kw + " = " + str(arg) for kw, arg in bound_siggy.arguments.items())
        print(f.__qualname__, "(", all_sargs, ")", sep = "")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

#### Issue: `str(arg)` is bad way to convert arguments into strings

I converted each argument `arg` into a string by writing `str(arg)`

Suppose that you pass a pandas dataframe into a function.

We can get some very ugly output.

The resulting string can contain new-line characters `\n` or carriage returns `\r`.

The strings could also be a mile long.

#### Issue: Cannot Get the Name of a Functor

Another issue with my attempts is that Functors (also known as "function objects") do not have an attribute named `__qualname__`. That is, if you define a class which has a `__call__` method, then we cannot easily print the name of the functor to a string.

```py
funky = Functor()
funky = decorate(funky)
r = funky(1, 2, 3, kwargy = int("python", 36))
# should print:
#     funky(1, 2, 3 kwargy = 1570137287)
```

Below is an example of a functor:

```py
# EXAMPLE OF A `FUNCTOR`
class Multiplier:   
    def __init__(self, m:int):
        self._m = int(str(m))
    def __call__(self, num:float)
        return num * self._m;

multi_the_multiplier = Multiplier(10**6)

# Decorate `multi_the_multiplier` with ` print_calling_args`
multi_the_multiplier = print_calling_args(multi_the_multiplier)

# ERROR: `multi_the_multiplier` does not have a `__qualname__`

r = multi_the_multiplier(1)
r = multi_the_multiplier(2)
r = multi_the_multiplier(3)
```