# How can we replace function parameters with string versions of the calling arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, calling-convention, introspection, code-inspection

Suppose that we have some function:

```py
def funky_the_function(pos_zero, pos_one, *, default=None, sep = " "):
    pass
```

Can you write a function-decorator which prints the function call?

That is, we want to print the function name along with the to-stringed arguments substituted into the function parameters.

```py
@print_calling_args
def funky_the_function(pos_zero, pos_one, *, default=None, sep = " "):
    pass

funky_the_function(1, 2, sep = "|-|")

# prints: `funky_the_function(1, 2, sep = "|-|")`
```

## Some Requirements:

- the names of key-word arguments must be shown provided that the key-word argument is not assigned a default value. For example, we might print `kwarg = 99`
- the names of positional arguments must be **NOT** shown. we print `1, 2` not `a = 1, b = 2`
- default values must not be printed.
- Each stringed argument must be at most 10 characters long. The 10 character limit does not include the keyword if the argument is a keyword argument
- Each stringed argument must not contain line-breaks
- We must have a function name for *functors* (class objects with a `__call__` method)

## Approach One

```py
def print_calling_args(f):
    assert(callable(f))
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        sargs     = ", ".join(str(arg) for arg in args)
        skwargs   = ", ".join(kw + " = " + str(arg) for kw, arg in kwargs.items())
        all_sargs = ", ".join((sargs, skwargs))
        print(f.__qualname__, "(", all_sargs, ")", sep = "")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

There are some issues with *Attempt One*. I will explain thee issues later.

## Approach Two (Using `inspect.getcallargs`)

```py
import inspect

def print_calling_args(f):
    assert(callable(f))
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        cargs = inspect.getcallargs(f, *args, **kwargs)
        print(cargs)
        all_sargs = ", ".join(kw + " = " + str(arg) for kw, arg in cargs.items())
        print(f.__qualname__, "(", all_sargs, ")", sep = "")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

## Approach Three (Using `inspect.signature`)

```py
import functools
import inspect

def print_calling_args(f):
    assert(callable(f))
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        siggy = inspect.signature(f)
        bound_siggy = siggy.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        all_sargs = ", ".join(kw + " = " + str(arg) for kw, arg in bound_siggy.arguments.items())
        print(f.__qualname__, "(", all_sargs, ")", sep = "")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

## Mistakes with my Attempts

#### Mistake: Printing Line Breaks and Overly Long Strings

> If you convert an argument to string by using `str(arg)` then the resulting string can contain new-line characters `\n` or carriage returns `\r`. For example, suppose you pass a pandas dataframe into a function?
>
> - I require that the stringed arguments all fit on one line (no line feeds)
> - I require that string arguments be shorter than one mile long (we must truncate the string)

We can truncate the strings as follows:

```py
def truncate(stryng:str, nchars:int = 10):
    # BEGIN ERROR CHECKING
    stryng = "".join(str(ch) for ch in stryng)
    nchars = int(str(nchars))
    # END ERROR CHECKING
    snip = " [...]"
    if nchars > len(stryng):
        return stryng
    return (stryng[:nchars - len(snip)] + snip)[:min(len(stryng), nchars)]
```

We can also get rid of the line-feeds (`\n`), etc....

```py
def sani(whole:str) ->str:
    """
        gets rid of all of the line-feed characters, 
        carriage-return characters, and other nasty characters in a string

        INPUT:
            A passage of English text containing new line character
                "hello\nworld"
                "hello" + chr(10) + "world"
        OUTPUT:
            string containing back-slash followed by a letter "n"
                "".join(["hello", chr(92), chr(110), "world"])  
    """  
    result = "\\".join(repr(part)[1:-1] for part in whole.split("\\"))
    return result
```

#### Mistake: Cannot Get the Name of a Functor

> Another issue with my attempts is that *Functors* (also known as "*function objects*") do not have an attribute named `__qualname__`. That is, if you define a class which has a `__call__` method, then we cannot easily print the function name to string. I require that we print something intelligible for *functors*; maybe the name of the class they are instantiated from followed by `()`.

```py
funky = Functor()
funky = decorate(funky)
r = funky(1, 2, 3, kwargy = int("python", 36))

# prints:
#     Functor()(1, 2, 3 kwargy = 1570137287)
```

Here is a functor:

```py
# EXAMPLE OF A `FUNCTOR`
class Multiplier:   
    def __init__(self, m:int):
        self._m = int(str(m))
    def __call__(self, num:float)
        return num * self._m;

multi_the_multiplier = Multiplier(10**6)

# Decorate `multi_the_multiplier` with ` print_calling_args`
multi_the_multiplier = print_calling_args(multi_the_multiplier)

# ERROR: `multi_the_multiplier` does not have a `__qualname__`

r = multi_the_multiplier(1)
r = multi_the_multiplier(2)
r = multi_the_multiplier(3)
```

Comment: Unless this is just an academic exercise, this reeks of the XY problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Do you need this for some real-world application?

Comment: What is wrong with attempt 1? It seems to get the name of the function correctly and there are no utterly long strings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print/log names and values of all parameters a function was called with (without eval)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353138/print-log-names-and-values-of-all-parameters-a-function-was-called-with-without)

Comment: In your decorator you can run additional check for functor. E.g. `if getattr(f, '__call__', None):
    callable_name = f.__call__.__qualname__` Here, f is a Functor instance. Returns `Functor.__call__`.

Comment: @fsimonjetz My question is almost a duplicate of the the question you linked to. However, I require a solution which works for class objects having a `__call__` method.

Comment: @jr15 An example of a real-world application would be to print a tree of function calls. `foo(1,2, 3)` called `bar("a", "b", "c")` and `bar` called `baz*(` It would be nice to use a logging library to print a log of everything that a program did. We could print `"while John was making dinner:\n\tJohn made a salad\n\t\tJohn chopped some lettuce"`

Comment: @DeepSpace You pointed out that for the test case I provided my code gets the function name without raising any exceptions and the stringed argument list looks pretty. However, most use-cases are not that simple. What if there is an input argument `arg` such that `len(str(arg)) > 100` or `"\n" in str(arg)`? That is not uncommon.

Comment: So this question becomes about "pretty" string formatting? For the `\n` case  you should be able to use `repr` instead of  `str`

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon if you're interested in printing function calls doesn't `traceback.print_stack()` help? It can be curated to list only the calls (invocation points) and no other information.