# print function that prints variable names and their values

Tags: python

For debugging I often want to print a variable out. I do this with for example:

print("cat_litter", cat_litter)

That is I print the variable name and its value. Is it possible to define a function to do this for me so I could call something like "printwithname(cat_litter)" for example.

Comment: No; `printwithname ` will only have the *value* of the variable, and not know where it came from.

Comment: Take a look at more recent f-strings, which support this directly! "a = 2; print(f'{a=}');" > will print "a=2".

Comment: @Brendano257 Thanks. What version of python does that need?

Comment: @ScottHunter yes. That's why I gave up and asked SO :)

Answer (score 9):

No function needed! Python 3.8+ f-strings support this kind of printing directly:

```
foo = 1
bar = 2
baz = "Something else"
print(f'{foo=}, {bar=}, {baz=}')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging

Python 3.6 -> 3.7 Workaround:

[Python: Print a variable's name and value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000934/python-print-a-variables-name-and-value)

Comment: What version of python does this need?

Comment: Python 3.6 or later with f string support.

Comment: @dawg thanks. I think 3.6 should be doable for me.  What can you do if you only have 3.5?

Comment: @Anush, I'd test this for yourself. This kind of f-string use is 3.8+, but f-strings themselves were included in 3.6. See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging

Comment: No good options prior to Python 3.6. Python variables do not general support name introspection other than with functions or writing your own object that does. You could look at the inspect module but really -- it is easier to upgrade to Python 3.6 or later.

Comment: The link is very helpful and also quite simple, thank you.

Comment: If you think this question has an answer somewhere else in this site - [flag it as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead of posting a link to an answer as an answer...