# Function argument for an f-string '=' debugging operator

Tags: python, debugging, f-string

How to pass a variable for an f-string '=' debugging operator?

```
from datetime import datetime


def print_var(var):

    print(str(datetime.now())[:19], end=' ')
    print(f'{var = }')


test = 5
print_var(test)
```

I expect `print_var(test)` to print the variable name from outside the function, ie.

`test = 5`

Please refer to [Python: Print a variable's name and value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000934/python-print-a-variables-name-and-value/57225950#57225950) for the context of the question.

Comment: The name isn't a property of the value. What would you expect for `print_var(some_list[index])`? `print_var(5)`?

Comment: are you expecting that variable name gets printed on the screen ?

Comment: @KunalSharma yes, I expect `print_var(test)` to print `test = 5` in the terminal window.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I should perhaps reformulate the question in the context of Python 3.8 f-string = syntax?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000934/python-print-a-variables-name-and-value/57225950#57225950

Comment: I'm familiar with the syntax, the problem is your expectation that it _wouldn't_ be the "local name", `var`. There are a bunch of possible dupes around getting the "outer name" (`test`, in this case), but all boil down to the same problem: the value might have been referred to by zero, one or many names, and none of them is a property of the value. Here's a good intro: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: something like this `2021-10-06 15:47:19 var = 5 test = 5`??

Comment: @jonrsharpe indeed, I expect the name from outside the function, thanks for reformulating.

Comment: @Sabil `2021-10-06 15:47:19 test = 5`

Comment: follow the flagged question, hope that will resolve your issue

Comment: @Sabil It does in part. I am looking for a production code solution.

Answer (score -2):

In f-strings you need to put the variable that needs to be printed between accolades. Like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
    
def print_var(var):
    print(str(datetime.now())[:19], end=' ')
    print(f'var = {var}')
```

Running the test yields the following:

```
test = 5
print_var(test)
>>>2021-10-06 11:32:05 var = 5
```

Comment: `f'var = {var}'` does the same thing that `f'{var = }'` does, just with more typing; the OP wants the name from _outside_ the function.