# Print ufloat variable name and value, not representation

Tags: python, formatting, uncertainty

There is a useful recent feature in python allowing one to print a variable's name and its value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57225950/6843348.  This doesn't quite work with the `uncertainties` library's `ufloat` type, because the representation is printed, losing the formatting.  Any suggestion to work around this?

```
from uncertainties import ufloat

x = ufloat(1.8768768, 0.0039788594)
print(x) # OK: 1.877+/-0.004
print(repr(x)) # 1.8768768+/-0.0039788594
print(f"{x=}") # Not OK: x=1.8768768+/-0.0039788594
```

EDIT Would prefer to enter the var name only once, and keep ufloat's formatting

Comment: Perhaps a question for https://stackoverflow.com/users/42973/eric-o-lebigot

Answer (score 0):

Change your print statement to:

```
print(f'x={x}')
```

Comment: Thanks!  That sort of solves it, but is clunky in the sense you need to enter the variable name twice.  Can it be simplified?

Comment: I was unable to find a more concise alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I HOPE YOU ARE DOING GREAT!!!
While using f-strings to print the variable name and its value with uncertainties' **ufloat type**, you can define a custom function that extracts the nominal value and standard deviation separately. FOR EXAMPLE:

```
from uncertainties import ufloat
```

def print_ufloat(var_name, value):
nom_value = value.nominal_value
std_dev = value.std_dev

```
print(f"{var_name}={nom_value:.3f}+/-{std_dev:.3f}")
```

x = ufloat(1.8768768, 0.0039788594)
print_ufloat('x', x)

Using this custom function, you can preserve the desired formatting for printing variable names and their values when working with uncertainties' **ufloat type.**

Comment: Thanks!  My impression is your solution requires to enter the var name and value, and overrides ufloat's formatting.  Have edited question to clarify that point.